# A typical HTTP session but Ajax style

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, session, asynchronous

Trying to understand the AJAX model internally.
According to [A typical HTTP session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session)

> In client-server protocols, like HTTP, sessions consist of three
>   phases:
>
> 1. The client establishes a TCP connection (or the appropriate
>      connection if the transport layer is not TCP).
> 2. The client sends its
>      request, and waits for the answer.
> 3. The server processes the request,
>      sending back its answer, providing a status code and appropriate
>      data.

How does that fit an AJAX call?

Is there a connection kept alive (in a different thread) with the server in the background so that the browser does not get blocked and can do other things?

Then when the result of the server is ready is it pushed down the browser 
through this 'hidden' connection and the browser then updates the DOM?

What I mean is, is there an open session maintained by AJAX, or is it closes and opens connections/sessions because the HTTP protocol is stateless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sessions are you talking about? An http/2 application will typically implement at least 4 session layers (yet some people still try to describe it in terms of the OSI model).

In terms of the thread of execution, JavaScript on a page runs as a single thread. But the thread is not blocked when you invoke send on the xmlhttprequest object if the third argument to the open method is true. If it is false, send() will block until it gets a response. For the asynchronous method, you would assign an action to carry out later when events are triggered by the request object. The low level handling of the interface between the xmlhttprequest and the underlying network stack behaves as if it were an autonomous thread of execution, but might be implemented in a select()/poll() operation as single thread - this is implemented inside the browser code, and therefore the question is only relevant if you happen to be writing a browser.

Comment: What I mean is ,is an Ajax call running in a background thread of the browser that opens and keeps an http connection to the server until the server returns the data and then it closes down the connection?the callback is then run on the main browser thread to update the dom

Comment: Of course the connection is handled while other things are happenning, but as I tried to explain above, not necessarily by a separate process/lwp. The TCP socket is unlikely to be closed immediately after the response is recvd